# NiFi: GetHTTP Processor Regular Expression Invalid Error

Tags: http, apache-nifi

I have a simple NiFi flow, with `GetHTTP` and `PutFile` processors. I am trying to connect the `GetHTTP` processor to the DC Metro data API, with this link:

```
https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType={contentType}
```

(The website can be [found here](https://developer.wmata.com/))

I can get this error:

[image]

I can't debug this error in the log, since it has not run yet. I also cannot find any other examples of this error. I put the link above in the `URL` part of the configuration, and gave it a sample `Filename` of `wmata_data.json`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having a **Newline** in the URL property value as shown below

[image]

To `resolve` the issue **Remove the newline** in URL property and try again.
[image]

Comment: That worked - but now it's giving me an SSL context error. Need to create one, I think? Thanks!

Comment: @papelr,Yes you need to create one, as you are using secured **https** instead of  open **http**.some references **https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/19476/connecting-to-facebook-graph-api-using-nifi-postht.html**

Comment: So for the the data API, I have a Primary key and a Secondary key, but I am not sure how to input that into the `SSLContextService` configuration. There are about 6 options, but where do I put my Primary and Secondary key?

Comment: @papelr,Sorry..!! i'm not sure about the configs of SSL context service, but give a try with **InvokeHTTP** processor instead of **GetHTTP** processor if doesn't work then please open a new question regards to the  how to configure `SSLContextService`..